# Stuck with this, dunno what to do $\int\ln\left(p^{f(s)}\right)\,ds$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

For up upcoming paper of mine: I need to pick some brains about rewriting $$\int\ln\left(p^{f(s)}\right)ds$$ where $f(s)$ is some polynomial in $s$. Twist: I do not know much about $p$. I can provide some more information if needed.
**Question:** How would you solve/rewrite this integral

1. if $p$ is NOT a function of $s$
2. how about if $p$ is some function of $s$ instead???

Comment: If $p$ is not a function of $s$ then this is just $\ln(p)\times \int f(s)\,ds$.

Comment: ah, of course. How about when $p=g(s)$ then. Can someone think of a way to do this

Comment: It's too broad.  All you get is $\int f(x)\ln p(s)\, ds$. But that's not any better than a general product of functions.